Heavy lamp hanging from ceiling?
I recently got a lovely lamp from someone (15lbs) that's meant to hang from a ceiling. I couldn't allow it to get discarded. But when I got it home I realised that it feels like something that's maybe too heavy to hang from our drywall ceiling. It's meant to hang and be plugged in, not be attached to a ceiling light fixture. This is new to me, is there some kind of limit for what can hang from drywall weight-wise? I dont know how to identify where the joists are. I suppose another thing I could do is hang it from a 12" bracket off the wall?

Nice stuff you want to be anchored to studs/ceiling joists, not drywall alone.  It has a chain so meant to hang off something.  This can be from the ceiling or a wall.  The length of the plug wire and the location of receptacles, will be important.  Adding a receptacle in a single family home can be DIY, multi-family/rentals require a licensed electrician.

Most ceiling lamps usually have at least one fixing into a joist, or are fixed through drywall / plasterboard into a batten also fixed between joists.

That would look nice on a wall bracket but it doesn't matter - ceiling or wall - you have to learn how to find and use the wood framing to attach it.  Make that your question.

Yes you wouldn't want to hang this just from drywall. You could use a ceiling fan rated box which supports up to 70 lbs, Attach that securely to the ceiling joists. Then you can buy a ceiling light canopy kit which allows you to hang the light from it and feed the wire into the electrical box. No need for a plug. Make sure it is a heavy-duty one as well. Random picture from the internet of a canopy kit:

